# Custom layout doesnt seem to be called

Tags: magento2

It seems when i debug my custom layout, it is not getting called!

**UPDATED ANS:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <action method="setTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">My Title</argument>
    </action>
</head>
<body>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::page/3columns.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <!-- <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Filter" name="custom_filter" before="-"/> -->
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Navigation" name="custom_filter" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block template="Vendor\Module::product/list.phtml" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product_list">
            <block template="Vendor\Module::toolbar.phtml" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

So when i hit the **localhost/magento/m/result/index** If my layout file is rendered, i should get the file in my custom debug file which logs the layout called.

**Controller path:** Controller/Result/Index.php

**layout file:** mypage_result_index.php

**router** :   route id="mypage" frontName="m"

Comment: any error are display?

Comment: No exception.log or error ...jus blank page

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, you have to replace **Vendor\Module with Vendor_Module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <action method="setTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">My Title</argument>
    </action>
</head>
<body>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::page/3columns.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Navigation" name="custom_filter" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product_list" template="Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml">
            <block template="Vendor_Module::toolbar.phtml" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have updated the answer @Rakesh, with Vendor_Module, but still it is not getting called!